# Password Parameters have been changed on the Domain controller

Tags: dns, active-directory, passwords, password-protection, domaincontroller

Is there a way where we can check if the Password Parameters have been changed on the Domain controller, Eg. Minimum password length is changed from 10 to 15 value.

can we check from any particular Event log?

Thanks in advance!!

check if the Password Parameters have been changed on the Domain controller

Comment: you can get password policy by PS cmd 'Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy' but if you want to track changes you must audit Default domain policy changes and add task (like send mail or popup msg) to specifics associated events. in DC security log. Have a look to 
https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/help/getting-started/domain-controllers-advanced-audit-policy.html

Comment: i want to the time stamp for which the activty was performed; As in the date when have the team changed the password length;

using this link i could, but does this also show the Time and date when this was done? https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/how-to/how-to-detect-changes-made-to-functional-level-in-active-directory.html

Comment: Yes of course : all events are time-stamped. have a look in your event viewer.